# Definite triple integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I need to evaluate the following triple integral

$$ \int_{-n}^n \int_0^{\sqrt{n^2-x^2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{n^2-x^2 -y^2}} \; e^{-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\; dz dydx 
$$

I converted this into the spherical coordinates. And the limits are as following

$$
 0 \leqslant r \leqslant n \\
0  \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 \leqslant \phi \leqslant \pi
$$

So, the integral becomes

$$
\int_0^n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\pi} e^{-n^3} \, r^2 dr \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi
$$

And after evaluating, I got the answer as

$$ 
\frac{\pi}{3}\, n^3 e^{-n^3} 
$$

Is this correct ? I tried to use Wolfram Alpha's triple integral calculator [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a83fc1af67a3fdc3cf56863e7f1b5dda) but it could not do it. So, please check my answer.

Comment: Why are you using LARGE font?

Comment: To make it look nice :)

Comment: It should be $e^{-r^3}$ not $e^{-n^3}$.

Comment: Please, don't do it again.Tex was made to be nice as it is, and there are standards that people are usual with. Everything that is out from that standards is usually seen as "non professional"

Comment: @PeterForeman has pointed out the problem in your computation. In case you want it in wolfram alpha: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B++r%5E2+Sin%5B%5C%5BTheta%5D%5D+Exp%5B-r%5E3%5D%2C+%7Br%2C+0%2C+n%7D%2C+%7B%5C%5BTheta%5D%2C+0%2C+%5C%5BPi%5D%2F+++2%7D%2C+%7B%5C%5BPhi%5D%2C+0%2C+%5C%5BPi%5D%7D%5D)

Comment: Thanks Peter. And will follow the guidelines. But small font is difficult to see.

Comment: But how would I enter the original integral in the Wolfram Alpha and evaluate it ?